# Windows 8.1 Pro won't upgrade to Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade

I have Windows 8.1 Pro installed and activated (of course with a legit key) and I want to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.

Everywhere I read about the upgrade it says I'm suppose to get the Pro version of Windows 10 because I got the Pro version of Windows 8.1. But this doesn't happen, but instead I get the Home version. Why?

I'm upgrading from Microsoft's web page.

Comment: Try using the [MediaCreationTool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and upgrade that way and see if it gives you pro otherwise maybe the key is registered wrong and you would need to contact Microsoft.

Comment: I am guessing you at some point upgraded to Windows 8.1 Professional from Windows 8/Windows 8.1.  Can you confirm that?

Comment: That's because your product key is stored in UEFI and the installer is reading that key. You need to follow the instructions on my provided duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Karl,

Edited:

Sorry about Ingored the orignal question, for the reason why it upgrade to Windows 10 home edition, it might be related with the original version which is pre-installed on your machine. You may need to contact the manufacturer to confirm this.

If you have the valid Windows 8.1 professional product key, then you could use that key to upgrade to Windows 10 professional from Windows 10 home:

[Upgrading Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-10/upgrade-windows-10-pro)

This requires the system to be under Windows 10 1511 version. If the key not work, you may contact the re-seller, or Microsoft support.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question at all.